# Como pegar objeto em php

Tags: php, angularjs

Boa noite pessoal,

Estou tentando passar parâmetros do meu controller para o php que faz busca no banco e não estou conseguindo. Estou passando os dados como objeto json.

controller:

```
var buscaCategorias = function(){

    var idempresa = $window.localStorage.getItem('idemp');
    var opcao = 'pegarCategoria';
    var buscaCat = {
        "opcao": opcao, 
        "idempresa": idempresa
    };

    console.log(buscaCat);

    $http.post('http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/buscaCatSubcat.php', buscaCat).success(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
};

buscaCategorias();
```

> Nesse console.log(buscaCat), o que mostra é Object {opcao: "pegarCategoria", idempresa: "3"}

PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($data);

$opcao = $data->opcao;

switch ($opcao) {
    case 'pegarCategoria':

        $idempresa = $data->idempresa;

        $buscaCategoria=$pdo->prepare("SELECT categoria, idcategoria FROM categoria WHERE empresa_idempresa=:idempresa ");
        $buscaCategoria->bindValue("idempresa", $idempresa);
        $buscaCategoria->execute();

        $return = array();

        while ($linhaCat=$buscaCategoria->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $linhaCat['categoria'] = $linhaCat['categoria'];
            $linhaCat['idcategoria'] = $linhaCat['idcategoria'];
            $return = $linhaCat;

        }

        echo json_encode($return);

        break;
```

Comment: Tá tentando passar um objeto no `$http.get`, isso funciona?

Comment: Não sei kkkkkkk

Comment: Será que só posso fazer isso usando $routeParams?

Comment: Não precisa de aspas que eu saiba dentro nas chaves do objeto **buscaCat**. `var buscaCat = {
        opcao : opcao, 
        idempresa: idempresa
    };`

Comment: Peguei esse exemplo do site da w3schools kkkkk

Comment: Já estou acessando o banco. Mas agora apenas 1 dado, de 2, está vindo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas aí.

Primeiro, o verbo **GET** não tem corpo, os dados **têm que ser passados na URL** via *querystring*.

Tanto que, se você abrir a documentação do [`$http.get`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) vai perceber que o segundo parâmetro se trata de um objeto de **configuração** e não os dados que você quer passar para o *server side*. A documentação diz:

> `config` | *Object* | Optional configuration object

Só sabendo disso você já vai precisar alterar algumas coisas (na aplicação e também repensar o que está fazendo).

Mas também tem um outro probleminha do lado do PHP.

**`file_get_contents("php://input");`** serve para obter os dados recebidos por **POST** e não por **GET**.

---

Possivelmente só alterar a requisição de GET pra POST já vai mostrar resultados.

```
$http.post('http://urlEnormeAqui/buscaCatSubcat.php', buscaCat).success(function(){ });
```

Comment: Você sugere que eu mude de .get para .post, então?

Comment: Eu não posso sugerir nada sem entender o que você precisa, mas disse que isso possivelmente vai trazer o resultado esperado.

Comment: Preciso busca dois dados do banco. Consegui trazer, mas apenas 1 deles está vindo.